# Python: how to generate a sample from Kernel density estimation?

Tags: python, sample, kernel-density

I need to download DJI stocks monthly prices and calculate monthly returns.
I have a data frame called 'data' which is the monthly prices of the stocks. I wanted to then use monthly returns and use kernel density estimation. I then want to withdraw  random sample from this and use it for generate 100 paths(monte carlo sumulation).
The problem is that when I generate the sample, the values are between 20 and 200. The returns data I gave it was in percentage so I thought the sample will be in percentage too? How can I get a random sample from KDE which corresponds to the original data (% returns)?
'data' has monthly prices, returns is the monthly returns, i thought new_data would be a sample from original data and would be in %

here is the code

```
returns=data.pct_change(1)
returns=returns.iloc[1:]
positive_returns = returns.apply(lambda x: x[x > 0].mean())
negative_returns = returns.apply(lambda x: x[x < 0].mean())
freq = returns.apply(lambda x: float(len(x[x > 0])) / float(len(returns)))


# use kernel density estimation to estimate the monthly return distribution for each stock
params = {'bandwidth': np.logspace(-1, 1, 20)}
grid = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(), params)
models = returns.apply(lambda x: grid.fit(x.values.reshape(-1, 1)).best_estimator_)


new_data=data.sample(60,random_state=0)
print(new_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using 'data' as your sample space for the new sample space. As given above, 'data' has the monthly prices, so not sure how would this give out percentages. A better alternative would be to use the returns dataframe for giving out new_data.

```
new_data=returns.sample(60,random_state=0)
```